# intval() in php returns empty string?

Tags: php

Can anybody explain to me why this (dubious, outdated and otherwise sinful) PHP code occasionally returns a string containing two asterisks characters one after the other? In other words, intval() occasionally returns an empty string.

What value avcost column could have had for that row (avcost is defined as double)?

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT avcost FROM singles" );
if (!$rows) return 5;
$buffer = "";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($rows))
{
    $avcost = intval($row[0]); // round it
    $buffer .= $avcost . "*";
}

echo $buffer; // Sometimes it echos something like: 5*0*3*0*34**4*5*
```

A full answer would include minimal corrections to the above code (without using something like "if ($avcost == "")" :-) that guarantee no double asterisk in the output. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of: `var_dump($row[0]);` ?

Comment: You probably have rows in your table where `avcost` is null (not the same as 0). You'll need to test explicitly and substitute an appropriate value.

Comment: But avcost is defined as double and not-nullable.

Comment: I don't know the output of var_dump($row[0]);. By the time I see this issue in the logs, the database has already changed, as a rule, and the issue cannot be reproduced at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

> A full answer would include minimal corrections to the above code (without using something like "if ($avcost == "")" :-) that guarantee no double asterisk in the output. Thank you.

I will try it :-)

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT `avcost` FROM `singles`");
if (!$rows) return 5;
$buffer = "";

if (mysql_num_rows($rows) == 0) return 5; // Just if you want

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
    $avcost = round($row['avcost']); // round it
    $buffer .= $avcost . "*";
}

echo $buffer; // Sometimes it echos something like: 5*0*3*0*34**4*5*
```

If it would not work, try this instead and provide me with the output:

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT `avcost` FROM `singles`");
if (!$rows) return 5;
$buffer = "";

if (mysql_num_rows($rows) == 0) return 5; // Just if you want

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows))
{
    $avcost = round($row['avcost']); // round it
    die(var_dump($avcost, intval($avcost), doubleval($row['avcost']), $row['avcost'])); // Debug purpose
    $buffer .= $avcost . "*";
}

echo $buffer; // Sometimes it echos something like: 5*0*3*0*34**4*5*
```